# How to encode / convert a complete folder using ffmpeg?

Tags: 16.04, video, ffmpeg, convert, convert-command

I have 20 music videos in one folder and I want to change the quality from 1080p to 720p with ffmpeg, because I'm tired of having to convert every single file.
 So I want to ask for a solution how to convert a complete folder 1 to 720p quality with destination folder 2?
I previously used this ffmpeg script

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -vf scale = 1280:720 -acodec aac -strict -2 output1.mp4
ffmpeg -i video2.mp4 -vf scale = 1280:720 -acodec aac -strict -2 output2.mp4
ffmpeg -i video3.mp4 -vf scale = 1280:720 -acodec aac -strict -2 output3.mp4
```

up to 20 times

I use ffmpeg on ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me restate your problem. You wish to:

1. process all the files named `video?.mp4`
2. generate an output filename `output?.mp4`
3. process the input file to the output file.

   `for i in video?.mp4 ; do
       outfile="output${i##video}"
       ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf scale=1280:720 -acodec aac -strict -2 "$outfile"
   done`

Read `man bash`